# Chat bots in Feathers

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, chatbot, feathersjs

Has anyone built chatbot functionality with Feathersjs? 
Currently trying to figure out if the [Botkit](https://howdy.ai/botkit/) framework will work (which would be great) or if I'll need to build something from scratch.
Thanks.

Comment: Planning to. Thank you for tipping me off on botkit!

Comment: @Samuel Are you working on the Feathers platform itself or working with it on your own? Curious about your approach.

Comment: I did not start yet. But that is my plan. To use feathersjs as the interface between API.AI and the db and other services. I did something similar last year in PHP.

Comment: @samuel would love to hear more as you go! Should be interesting work to explore. Trying to come up with a similar flow myself, but focusing on feathers + react integration first.